# Initial Burst node stream

Tags: node.js, stream

anyone knows how to create a node js stream with an initial burst ?

Lets say we have an mp3 stream, the first second after a user starts the stream {s}he should be provided with a high rate and after some seconds the bit rate should reduced.

I tried reshaper but after changing the rate the stream stops with an chunk error.

Comment: Stream is a sequence of bytes, so you need to find a way how to increase the rate for your given case. It has nothing to do with streams in general

Comment: Yeah I know :) but how to solve

Comment: you need to find a way how to increase it in general first, than you can split your file into two parts: one with normal rate, another with amplified